# Обособление названия: "Второй фильм «Счастливое детство»"

Tags: приложение

Он работает над вторым полнометражным фильмом «Счастливое детство».

Он работает над новой книгой «Несчастливое детство».

Обязательно ли здесь приложение («Счастливое детство» и  Несчастливое детство») обособлять?

Comment: По-моему, тут не надо названия обособлять ни в коем случае.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Обязательно ли здесь приложение («Счастливое детство» и Несчастливое
>   детство») обособлять?

По-моему, обязательно:  из-за наличия перед определяемым словом согласованного определения *(**вторым** фильмом...; **новой** книгой...)*. И лучше с помощью тире:

***Он работает над вторым полнометражным фильмом  — «Счастливое детство».***

***Он работает над новой книгой  — «Несчастливое детство».***

Answer (score 1):

Если исходить из того, что первый фильм или книга имели другое название, то какой-то знак необходим, иначе двусмысленность получается. И slava1947 прав - лучше тире.

*Не знаю, правда, насколько правомерным будет такую пунктуацию назвать "обособлением", но это другой вопрос, не будем в дебри влезать.*